# Where is Notification composer in Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

Is Cloud Messaging section removed in the Firebase Console? I also tried to check the documentation but it just redirects me to Firebase Console projects.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-with-console

Comment: Please check the all products section in your firebase console.

Comment: @Tunahan oh crap, so they merge In-App Messaging and Cloud Messaging in one section. Thanks!

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS do you have any more details? Both "In-App Messaging" and "Cloud Messaging" take me to the same page, and there is nothing called "Notifications composer".

I can just create campaigns, and view reports

Comment: hey @user1150316 in the "campaigns" page there are two buttons "new experiment" and "new campaign", white and blue button respectively, click the white one, "new experiment", it will show you two potions "notifications" and "in-app messages", the first one is the notification composer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I can't figure out how you're supposed to get there from the console, if you go to the link directly it works. The link is different for each of your projects, though:

`https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<projecthere>/notification/compose`

If you go to the following link and have more than one project, it will prompt you to click a project and then take you to the composer:

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification/compose

This was really frustrating to me. I am not sure they are aware that a large amount of their documentation says to go to a thing that seems impossible to find.